# How do I get a RequestScope in a MessageDrivenBean in Wildfly 8.1.0?

Tags: scope, jms, wildfly, wildfly-8, jboss-weld

When my message driven bean is called in Wildfly 8.1.0, the container does not initialize a RequestScope. So when I try to inject my EntityManager via CDI by a RequestScope Producer, I get the exception:

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: **WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped**
>    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:680)
>    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:733)
>   [...]

**Shouldn't there be an initialized RequestScope also if it is a call via JMS?** or do I have a wrong Idea on how to implement this.

I found org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor which I guess internally is responsible to initialize the RequestScope, but I could also not figure out yet, if I could register this interceptor on the JMS Bean.

Comment: There should be a @RequestScope in existence during MDB message processing. Perhaps you should show some code.